# JasperReports NoClassDefFoundError exception on net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser

Tags: java, jasper-reports

When trying to export on WebLogic 11g, it throws NoClassDefFound exception. I checked the application WAR and jasperreports-3.7.4.jar is included in WEB-INF/lib folder. What is the error?

**StackTrace**

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRStyledTextParser
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.(JRBaseFiller.java:181)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:76)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:86)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:56)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:142)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:78)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.fillReport(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:676)
>     at

Comment: Isn't there a root cause? Look further in the trace. Initialization of the class might have plain failed.

Comment: Are there multiple jasperreport jars in the web app or classpath.

Comment: @JoseK It seems that only one jar exists on classpath. I tried to deploy this WAR without Jasperreport.jar in it, but it throws exception for NoClassDefFound on Jasper classes.

Comment: It might be cached in the tmp_delete folders within the weblogic domain - can you delete all that and try?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Finally, I've got it working. I detected the root Exception, which was thrown before NoClassDefFoundError:net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRStyledTextParser :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/awt/X11GraphicsEnvironment
```

The Sun AWT classes on Unix and Linux have a dependence on the X Window System. When you use these classes, they expect to load X client libraries and be able to talk to an X display server. This makes sense if your client has a GUI; unfortunately, it's required even if your client uses AWT but does not have a GUI (which is my case, generating a report from a web application)

The way to bypass this, is setting a system property `java.awt.headless=true` on system startup.

Comment: Has anyone had trouble using the java.awt.headless=true solution on different machine? It is working for us on one of our deployments, while not working on another. Both of the deployments are using the same JVM version.

Comment: Worked to me! My server is the [Weblogic 12c](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-main-097127.html). I added the `-Djava.awt.headless=true` value in server initialize arguments, exactly in Server Resume tab.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same issue and we've solved it by installing the xorg fonts packages along with the ttf fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Text Parsing Exception means the font not have been recognized. I spent an whole day trying to understand why, then finally I fix this problem using text SansSerif. On Linux only a few font can be parsed. Hoping has helped,
best regards

Answer (score 1):

We had similar issue. we resolved it by using the jasper java flow jar file. the

```
java.awt.headless=true
```

didn't work for us.

Comment: Could you please share some details as to how you achieved this? I'm having the same problem and I tried using the java flow jar but that's not working either for me. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: where exactly need to add this line?

Comment: @Elango  You need to set the java.awt.headless property to true. That can be done using:
static {
    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
}
Or, by setting the headless property in your tomcat startup command as -Djava.awt.headless=true

Answer (score 1):

This was due to a missing font. I was able to resolve this by installing fontconfig and urw-fonts packages.

```
yum install fontconfig
yum install urw-fonts
```

After that you can check supported fonts using command

```
fc-list
```

If the reports are still not generated you may need to reboot the server.

Answer (score 0):

You get the same error if there is no enough space. I had the same error and it was because there was 0KB free space on server's hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was resolved by reducing the /tmp space. It was 100%  (/tmp folder). I reduced it to 86% and restarted the server and the noclassdefinitionerror was gone and issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue multiple times and I have got the solution. 
This error comes due to lack of memory space on disk... 
You can try below things to solve :
(i) Make enough space in tmp folder 
(ii) Delete some unnecessary files on the disk to make some space.

Good luck..Hope.. it should solve your issue

Comment: what do you mean by temp folder

Answer (score 0):

Once you have this problem, googling will bring you here. For me the problem was Jdk 11.2.

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:84)
        ... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1262)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:225)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:719)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:367)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:312)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:56)
        ... 90 more
java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:86)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getFontManagerForSGE(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:189)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:223)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:251)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:75)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:94)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:110)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:69)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:57)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:200)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:215)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:115)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:667)
```

Solutions tried

- Ran locally with JDK 11.02. No problems. Because the problems happens
  on linux 64 systems
- Ran on server -Djava-awt.headeless=true as
  suggested by some users . Problem still remains.

Reason this problem occurs is because support of certain fonts have been removed

From Oracle release notes
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#Removed

> Removal of Lucida Fonts from Oracle JDK  Oracle JDK no longer ships
>   any fonts and relies entirely on fonts installed on the operating
>   system.
>
> This means that fonts in the Bigelow & Holmes Lucida family (Lucida
>   Sans, Lucida Bright, and Lucida Typewriter) are no longer available to
>   applications from the JDK.
>
> If applications rely on fonts shipped in the JDK, they may need to be
>   updated.
>
> If system adminstrators are running Java server applications that rely
>   on fonts shipped in the JDK rather than on system font packages, then
>   the applications may fail to run until the system font packages are
>   installed.

Go back to previous version of JDK or you can try upgrading Jasper.

Answer (score 0):

for my case, jasperreports 6.8.0, worked the change of project dependency xml-apis from version

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

to

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
```

as proposed in jaspersoft community forum https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/825173/could-not-initialize-class-netsfjasperreportsengineutiljrstyledtextparser

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the xfce4 font package in my alpine linux. In fact, I'm using docker. So, I put the following command in the dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add xfce4
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me just installing the fontconfig library on the so.

```
apt install fontconfig
```