# How to run jasper report in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports

I have a simple jasper report which shows some data from database. The jasper report runs well on ireport designer. The problem is when i try to run the report from servlet. I am trying to export the report as pdf when running from a servlet.
I included dependencies like

```
- jasperreports-4.6.0.jar
- itextpdf-5.1.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
- commons-digester3-3.2.jar
- cglib-2.2.jar
```

I have placed my report1.jasper file inside /web/report1.jasper
Here is my servlet file:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Connection connection;
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream =response.getOutputStream();

    InputStream reportStream =getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/report1.jasper");

    HashMap parameterMap = new HashMap();
    String stdID="510BCT2010";
    String semester="1";
    parameterMap.put("stdID", stdID);
    parameterMap.put("semester", semester);
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:odbc:ACEM","","");
        JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream,servletOutputStream, parameterMap, connection);

        connection.close();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // display stack trace in the browser
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
        e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getOutputStream().print(stringWriter.toString());
    }
}
```

When I run the servlet for the first time, i get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Rule
net.sf.jasperreports.components.ComponentsExtensionsRegistryFactory.<clinit>(ComponentsExtensionsRegistryFactory.java:100)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:157)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ClassUtils.instantiateClass(ClassUtils.java:53)
net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.instantiateRegistry(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:237)
net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:214)
net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:162)
net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:133)
net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:105)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:83)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:153)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:55)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:407)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:201)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:720)
com.reports.reportGenerator.doGet(reportGenerator.java:54)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

When i run the servlet after that i get following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:153)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:55)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:407)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:201)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:720)
com.reports.reportGenerator.doGet(reportGenerator.java:54)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

It says java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. Have I missed some dependencies? My report has no graphs, only fetches data from a database

Comment: Please have a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628302/jasperreports-noclassdeffounderror-exception-on-net-sf-jasperreports-engine-util][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628302/jasperreports-noclassdeffounderror-exception-on-net-sf-jasperreports-engine-util

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Jasper report library dependencies depends upon its version. jasperreport 4.6 requires [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download). Also I had new itext library (5.1), but jasper report 4.6 still uses iText-2.1.7.

Answer (score 1):

It seems apache commons digester is missing in your dependencies, given the stacktrace.