# create report in pdf by using jasper and servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports

I want to create a report in pdf format by using servlet, .jasper file,but there is a **exception:**

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception
>
> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet execution threw an exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling     this request.
>
> exception
> ```
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperRunManager
>     one.Patient.doGet(Patient.java:46)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.34 logs.
>
> ---

servlet code is:

```
package one;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

//import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Patient
 */
@WebServlet("/Patient")
public class Patient extends HttpServlet implements Servlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Patient() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Connection con=DBCon.getConnection();
        InputStream inS=getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/report-src/ganeshaji.jashper");

        OutputStream outS=response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        try {
            JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(inS, outS, new HashMap<String, Object>(),con);
            outS.flush();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

pls. provide me solution

Answer (score 3):

By looking into the root Cause

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperRunManager
```

it seems like you either miss the jasper jar or have the wrong version which doesn't support JasperRunManager.

Including the proper jar in the class path will solve your issue.

Please download these jars:

```
itext-4.2.0.jar 

itextpdf-5.3.4.jar 

jasperreports-4.0.1.jar 

jasperreports-fonts-4.0.0.jar
```

and code something like:

```
try { 
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(YOURREPORTPATH.jasper"); 
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fis); 
jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(bufferedInputStream); 
} catch (Exception e2) {
 e2.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

and then after filling the parameters and the datasource create pdf like this:

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, OUTPUTFILENAME+".pdf");
```

Thanks...

Mr.777

Comment: sir i include this jasperreports-4.1.2.jar

Comment: Please download these jars:


itext-4.2.0.jar
itextpdf-5.3.4.jar
jasperreports-4.0.1.jar
jasperreports-fonts-4.0.0.jar

and code something like:

try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(YOURREPORTPATH.jasper");
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(bufferedInputStream);
   } catch (Exception e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
   }


and then after filling the parameters and the datasource create pdf like this:

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, OUTPUTFILENAME+".pdf");

Comment: Did you try using the above mentioned steps?

Comment: sir i got it - my mistake is that i am added all liabraries in build configuration path and another fault is in .jrxml file language=groovy

Comment: so i added all library in the webcontent\lib folder of project and delete the language= groovy from .jrxml file ..........

Answer (score 0):

detected the root Exception, which was thrown before NoClassDefFoundError:net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRStyledTextParser :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/awt/X11GraphicsEnvironment
```

The Sun AWT classes on Unix and Linux have a dependence on the X Window System. When you use these classes, they expect to load X client libraries and be able to talk to an X display server. This makes sense if your client has a GUI; unfortunately, it's required even if your client uses AWT but does not have a GUI (which is my case, generating a report from a web application)

The way to bypass this, is setting a system property `java.awt.headless=true` on system startup.

**For Example**

**Let java execute the static block as early as possible by moving it to the top of the class!**

```
  public class Foo() {
    static { /* works fine! ! */
      System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
      }

     public static void main() {}
  }
```

**or**

I think this parameter can be set by passing it as an argument to Java Virtual Machine e.g.

-Djava.awt.headless=true. Not sure if this would have impact on other components of your application.

**or**

Try putting this in your ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina.sh script:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

refered from-https://stackoverflow.com/a/3651196/1602230

Comment: Sir can you elaborate how to set system property java.awt.headless=true on system startup.

Comment: I paste java.awt.headless=true in boot.ini on system startup.