# Unexpected exception while filling JasperReports report - Could not initialize net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser (GWT)

Tags: java, gwt, jasper-reports, cloud, noclassdeffounderror

I am building a website with GWT and I want to incorporate a report generator in the site using *JasperReports*. All the data the report draws are store in a database in cloud, so I use an instance and cloud sql to connect to the database and retrieve/store data (basically a user table). The user is supposed to login with some credentials and then by pressing a button "download" they should be able to get the generated report in pdf form. I have implemented this with an RPC process.

The problem is that when the `JasperFillManager.fillReport` method is called so as to fill the report, I get the following exception

```
    SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.MyProject.website.client.ReportService.createReport(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Font is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:383)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Font is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.<init>(SimpleFontFace.java:100)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.<init>(SimpleFontFace.java:128)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.getInstance(SimpleFontFace.java:67)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFamily.setNormal(SimpleFontFamily.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamily(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:261)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:232)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:193)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:162)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:56)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:110)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:83)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:153)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:55)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)
    at com.MyProject.website.server.ReportServiceImpl.createReport(ReportServiceImpl.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 38 more

Could not generate the report
```

If I press the download button again (without having changed anything) I get a slightly different exception

```
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.MyProject.website.client.ReportService.createReport(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:383)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:153)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:55)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)
    at com.MyProject.website.server.ReportServiceImpl.createReport(ReportServiceImpl.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 38 more

Could not generate the report
```

After looking for a while in the internet I read on SO that this might be a missing library issue so I added some extra libraries from the JasperReports distribution to the classpath of my project. The files that are in the classpath now (from the JR distribution) are:

1. commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
2. commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
3. commons-digester-2.1.jar
4. commons-javaflow-20060411.jar
5. commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
6. iText-2.1.7.js1.jar
7. jasperreports-5.0.0.jar
8. jasperreports-fonts-5.0.0.jar
9. jasperreports-javaflow-5.0.0.jar

Yet, I still get the same exception thrown...

Any hint of where should I look for the problem?

I post here the code for the downloadReport function as well as the for the RPC methods

**downloadReport method**

```
void downloadReport(String username, String password){
    // create the report and get it
    ReportService.Util.getInstance().createReport(username, password, new AsyncCallback<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result){ // the URL of the created report file is returned
            text1.setText(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught){
            System.out.println("Could not generate the report");
        }
    }); 
}
```

**ReportService.java**

```
package com.MyProject.website.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("ReportService")
public interface ReportService extends RemoteService {

    public static class Util {

        private static ReportServiceAsync instance;

        public static ReportServiceAsync getInstance() {

            if (instance == null) {
                instance = GWT.create(ReportService.class);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    String createReport(String name, String password);

}
```

**ReportServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.MyProject.website.server;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

import com.MyProject.website.client.ReportService;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;


import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.BaseHttpServlet;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ReportServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements ReportService{

    @Override
    public String createReport(String name, String password) {

        String temp = null;
        Connection c = null;
        Map<String, Object> rParamet = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        try {
              DriverManager.registerDriver(new AppEngineDriver());
              c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://MyProject:dbutest/DBtest");
              rParamet.put("email", name);
              rParamet.put("password", password);
              rParamet.put("ReportTitle", "Test Report");
              String sourceFile = this.getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF") + "/testReport.jasper";

              try {
                JasperPrint reportPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(sourceFile, rParamet, c);
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(reportPrint, "ReportTest");
              } catch (JRException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (c != null) 
                  try {
                    c.close();
                  } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                  }
            }

            // More code to be added here for getting the report URL

        return temp;
    }



}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you see this questions: [JasperReports NoClassDefFoundError exception on net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3628302/876298) & [create report in pdf by using jasper and servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15066892/876298)?

Answer (score 0):

From the first stack trace: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Font is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.`

That guide it refers to is https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

So:

- either you want to make reports in an app that'll be deployed to AppEngine, and you have to find another library, as JasperReports doesn't work in that environment
- or you don't intend to run on AppEngine and you misconfigured your project

Comment: No I intent to run on AppEngine. I guess I have to find another solution. Thank you for your answers though!