# Jasperreport in Java 11. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser

Tags: java, jasper-reports, java-11

I run jasperreports inside docker **openjdk:11.0.1-jdk-slim** without error.

Inside **openjdk:11.0-jdk-slim** (openjdk version "**11.0.6**" 2020-01-14) error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:982)
    ... 116 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:116)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:79)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:251)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:272)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:156)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:145)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:758)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:1074)
    at com.keyintegrity.shb.common.report.ReportManager.writeReport(ReportManager.java:57)
    at com.keyintegrity.shb.rest.DealController.writeReport(DealController.java:268)
    at com.keyintegrity.shb.rest.DealController.getDealApplicationStateReport(DealController.java:211)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    ... 116 common frames omitted
```

[Here is describe in java 11  fonts was removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55247387/12146765)

Is it possible to install this font?

In [article](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Font+Setup#FontSetup-HostSystemFonts) should exist lib
`find /usr/lib -name libfontconfig.so -o -name libfontconfig.so.1`

Comment: Can you please add the complete Stacktrace?

Answer (score 2):

Found solution, create container:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0-jdk-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libfontconfig1 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```